# Stopping tomcat7 [FAILED] with Grails 2.3.7 and AWS

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an application two weeks ago using Grails 2.3.7, and uploaded the application on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. Everything was ok until this morning. I modified some GSPs and tried to deploy, but I have this error:

```
[ERROR] Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command hooks failed .
[ERROR] Failed to signal process manager to stop tomcat: Stopping tomcat7: [FAILED]
```

Everything is ok when I launch the app on my desktop.

And now, I don't know what I can do =/

Any help is welcome!

My configuration on AWS:
- Tomcat 7 on 32bits Linux
- PostgreSQL DB with RDS

Thanks for reading.

Comment: did you have a look into catalina.out ?

Comment: I didn't see so much things on catalina.out. I tried to rebuild the environnement and it works again. I don't know what happened.

Comment: Hi john, it appends again after a "yum update" on my EC2. I tried your command, I restarted my app-server... THANK YOU BECAUSE IT WORKS :)

Comment: youre welcome, unfortunately i haveno idea what the real problem is :/ main thing is it works ;D

Comment: Yes, it works, so it is ok :) But the problem is still here when i try the upload and deploy button. I'll try to create another app, with Tomcat 7 and Linux 64bits. My Grails App is using tomcat 7.0.47 and the last update on my EC2 is tomcat 7.0.37.